# Best practice for cascading changes of duplicate properties across different entities in google datastore?

Tags: java, database, google-cloud-datastore

hi there i have been working on a project with datastore for some time and was wondering if there are some best practices other than to check/update it in my code..

so if i have a property a that is part of entity A and also B 
and my code supports updating A, does datastore support referencing properties or cascading changes?

Answer (score 0):

No, the datastore does not support entity relationships like a SQL database. It must be done manually in every entity. In most cases, it is advisable to make the call that changes the entities idempotent.